# Edit preview and actual question appearance not matching

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just noticed that my preview is not matching the actual appearance of the question.

See this question:
[Is there a Combat log?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55753/is-there-a-combat-log)

The problem in edit box

[image]

The problem in preview

[image]

The problem when seeing the question. Note that the image is not on the next line (correctly).

[image]

Comment: I was just having a similar issue, one segment of code disappeared on me and another got stuffed into one line. Happened twice; first time took two additional edit->save cycles to right itself, second only one.

Comment: have you read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help may this help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the editor's preview container on Gaming being 20px narrower than the final, rendered output's container.

When the preview is the same width, the image is on the same line as the text (which is correct according to [markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks)).

Pinging our designer [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) to unleash his CSS powers.

Comment: I tried to leave the question in its `errored` state. However, someone has corrected it and some spelling. Feel free to roll it back!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this up. While the size of the preview factored in, as Jarrod mentioned, ultimately the Markdown was written such that the image and text would be on the same line. To ensure that images and text are on new lines, they must be separated by a blank line.

Same line Markdown:

```
Text
[Image]
```

New line Markdown:

```
Text

[Image]
```